# Microsoft Dynamics CRM: find cases that have been close within 2 days

Tags: find, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, case, crm

I'm trying to generate a list of all cases in a system that has been closed within 2 days, but don't know what is the base way to do it, apart from running through all the cases and comparing created on with resolved by date. Are there any other ways to do it? Are there build in function to solve such a trivial task?

Thank you

Comment: I changed the tag to your question, you didn't specify the version of Dynamics CRM (4.0 or 2011) feel free to edit your post and make a correction

Comment: About your question, did you try using Advanced Find?

Comment: I don't think an advanced find will allow you to do this, but a custom report most certainly will. Fire up the report wizard and you should be able to make this in fairly short order.

Answer (score 2):

When a Case/Incident is resolved a new record is created: **Case Resolution**
This is a semi-hidden CRM record type.

You can use Advanced Find to create a view of this:

[image: Advanced Find for Case Resolution Activity Type]

This will allow you to create a view. Unfortunately you can't then include this view in your list of Incident Views (along with Active Cases, Resolved Cases, etc)

Comment: It's an Activity? Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoGomes Yes, it inherits from the base `Activity` type